# jstree with grid apple theme can never align with the font

Tags: themes, alignment, jstree

How to make text in jstree with grid to align with the background lines in apple theme? Seems it never works correct in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jstree grid is not strong enough for my implementation. I end up using jqGrid.